# how to apply condition on fetching data from api?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

currently i am using fakestoreapi, here i am passing category parameter to fetch data from api.

> ```
> const res = await fetch(`https://fakestoreapi.com/products/${category}`)
> ```

and displaying products from fetched data

> ```
> {products.map((product, index) => (
>                         <div key={product.id} className="w-full max-w-sm text-black rounded-lg shadow-md bg-white justify-bitween cursor-pointer ">
>                             <Link to={`/${product.category}/${product.id}`}>
>                                 <img className="p-2 rounded-t-lg w-full h-[150px] md:h-[200px] object-contain" src={product.image} alt="productimage" />
>                             </Link>
>                             <div className="px-5 pb-2">
>                                 <Link to={`/${product.category}/${product.id}`}>
>                                     <h5 className="text-[15px] font-semibold tracking-tight text-gray-900 hover:text-blue-700">{product.title.slice(0, 30)}...</h5>
>                                 </Link>
>                                 <div className="flex items-center justify-between py-4">
>                                     <span className="text-2xl sm:text-2xl font-bold text-gray-900 ">${product.price}</span>
>                                     <button className="hidden sm:block text-white bg-indigo-500 hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 text-center dark:bg-indigo-500 dark:hover:bg-blue-800  dark:focus:ring-blue-800" onClick={() => addToCart(product)}>Add to cart</button>
>                                 </div>
>                             </div>
>                         </div>
>                     ))}
> ```

but now i do not want to display all product of that category how to do that?

how to show selective or remove unwanted product details fetched from that id?

Comment: add a filter like this {products.filter( xxx ).map((product, index) => (. More info on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 0):

Fakestore API can receive a `limit` query parameter :

```js
fetch('https://fakestoreapi.com/products/category/jewelery?limit=2')
  .then(res=>res.json())
  .then(json=>console.log(json))
```

> You can also use limit(Number) and sort(asc|desc) as a query string to get your ideal results

https://fakestoreapi.com/docs

Comment: This does not answer OP's question.